# How to delete this faces

Tags: faces, extrude

[image]

i extrude the middle faces going down but i can't delete the extra faces even after typing "X" and select edge or vertices still non of em help plz help thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for deleting Faces is by making loopCut and merge them to the vertex u want to delete

Link of Video here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H3NENyaaiis68ZoZlMjKOYRwEYBqlXQ2/view?usp=sharing

(for documentation)